# Transform Oracle sql syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to change the syntax of an Oracl SQL Query,

The original query contains a join:

```
WHERE (A.ID = B.ID OR A.ID is null)
```

I would like to change this to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` syntax,

I tried the following but the query doesn't return the same results:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA A ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample

Comment: I think we might need to see more details, since that looks ok - the first example has a where clause in parens though which looks odd.

Comment: Another thought, there's a huge difference between LEFT OUTER and INNER; what records do you want to include?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I mean, what do you expect after you complete that task?

Comment: Check my last edit @Andrew

Comment: In fact, they do not return the same results.  In general, the `left join` is what is needed.  On occasion the `where` version is the version that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an outsider, I can't say for sure, but I strongly suspect that the person who wrote

```
WHERE (A.ID = B.ID OR A.ID is null)
```

was trying to do an outer join and just got it completely wrong.  That condition is not logically equivalent to an outer join.

Consider:

```
with a ( id, val ) as ( 
SELECT 1, 'a one' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a two' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'a three' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 'a null' FROM DUAL ),
b ( id, val ) as ( 
SELECT 2, 'b two' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'b three' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'b four' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 'a null' FROM DUAL )
select a.id aid, a.val aval, b.id bid, b.val bval
from a, b
where ( a.id = b.id or a.id is null )

+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| AID |  AVAL   | BID |  BVAL   |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
|   2 | a two   |   2 | b two   |
|   3 | a three |   3 | b three |
|     | a null  |   2 | b two   |
|     | a null  |   3 | b three |
|     | a null  |   4 | b four  |
|     | a null  |     | a null  |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
```

... you can see the null value for `a.id` got joined to *every* row in table b.  If there were no row in table a with a null `id`, there would have been no row having b.id = 4 (only the 1st two records above would have been returned).

An outer join of the same data should look like this:

```
select a.id aid, a.val aval, b.id bid, b.val bval from b left join a
on a.id = b.id order by a.id, b.id

+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| AID |  AVAL   | BID |  BVAL   |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
|   2 | a two   |   2 | b two   |
|   3 | a three |   3 | b three |
|     |         |   4 | b four  |
|     |         |     | a null  |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
```

My advice: understand what the query is *supposed* to do.  If the requirements of the query are to outer join, fix the query to be an outer join and ignore what it used to do -- it was wrong.